# Facebook current notifications count

Tags: php, facebook

I am finding it very difficult to find any information on how to retrieve the count of all currently unread notifications of the current session user. Ideally i would just like to return a number via php to html of all unread notifications. What i would like to do is pool for notifications every minite or so and if there is a new one i would like to be alerted and the status updated. I have tried this via the array from getNotifications but no luck. Is counting the current unread notifications even possible ?????. Basically i am asking how current smartphones are getting the count and alerting users to when there is a new notification etc.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Did you check that : http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/notification/ ?

I guess you can check every minute the unread notification of a user, record them in the database, and if a new one appear (ie wasn't present in the previous request), you update the status of the user